# SwiftUI Date picker show only month or only year

Tags: datepicker, swiftui

Is there any possibility to show only month or only year in Picker?

```
DatePicker(selection: $rkManager.minimumDate, in: Date().defaultDateFrom...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
   Text("")
}
```

Comment: @Chris Can show me sample code if you have free time? Didn't do that before